# How to make jquery accordion not change color when selected without removing possibility to hover

Tags: jquery, css

In the example on jquery webpage when selecting a heading the color is changed:

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Is there a way to make it so that the color stay the same?

I have tried following and it works but it introduces the issue that it removes the hover functionality so when i hover the heading it stays the same.

```
.ui-state-active
{
    background: // same color as default       
}
```

Is there a way to remove the active state for the clicked heading in the accordion (I have tried and failed, but maybe I'm doing it wrong) or is there another way to go about it?

Comment: ah.. why don't you just change the CSS: background-color to the same as default state when hover ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always override the `jquery-ui.css` classes. Try this in your own CSS (**Note: Your CSS should be included after `jquery-ui.css`**):

```
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
   background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #e6e6e6;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have tried that and what happens is that first when I hover it works as it supposed to and whan I click on it it gets to the default apperance, but after that when I try to hover again it is locked in a state and does not hover.

So I figured what's needed is to get the clicked accordion caption out of the active or visited state or whatever the state it is in that prevent it from hovering. But I don't know how to do that.